# What is the opposite of a glossy display?

Tags: displays

I currently have a laptop with a display I would describe as "glossy". When the screen is dark you can perfectly see your mirror image. Unfortunately this is often very inconvenient because bad lighting immediately makes the screen unusable. That's why I would like to avoid this for my next purchase.

Can you please tell me what these kinds of matt displays are called so I can properly search for it?

Comment: While this question is not asking for technical _support_, it is asking for technical _details_. This site exists to help others find computer hardware that performs a specific task. Basically, this question is not asking for a specific hardware recommendation. Please read the [on-topic help center](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: It is asking for how to ask for that specific piece of hardware. Knowing this is a prerequisite to using this site. I find that rather useful to have here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have been trying to find a meta post where we talked about questions like these, but I can only find the  [one](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/60). We as a community have had a hard time in the past with "pre purchase" questions like this one, and have had much discussion not only in meta, but also on chat. If I am able to find anything else, I will be sure to post it here.

Comment: @Cfinley It's fine you probably know what you are doing and my post is indeed not asking about a specific hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for either matte surface or anti-glare ones.

The rough matte surface panels are still mostly used in the business notebook segment. The other type of anti-glare computer screens, which uses a chemical coating over a smooth surface to cut down glare, is more used on glare panels to minimize the amount of glare there.

Anti-glare surfaces have a smooth surface but reduced reflection.
Matte has a rough surface and no reflection.